# test a monitoring tool

Tags: testing, jmeter, functional-testing, performance-testing

please guide me how to test a monitoring tool?
Due to the nature of the project (a program that monitor another target program), we cannot expect the input (activity of target program) and hence what is the best way to test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly how your monitoring tool is working, but I think that some how it communicates with some 'target' applications, retrieve data from them and displays a report.

I think that your problem is that you cannot control the input to your monitoring tool, in order to test that it displays correct data, because that input depends on your target apps.

My suggestion is to create a `Mock` application. This app must have the same interface with your real target app so your tool can communicate with it. Of course, the implementation must be different. Implement it with that way, so that every parameter is checked by your tool will be configurable to you. So, you will be able to know which will be the input to your tool.

Comment: as you mentioned my monitoring tool is talking to an application "target" but I have to test the monitoring tool itself. so what type of software I can use for testing this tool?

Comment: Before looking for the tool you have to write down the Test Cases which are testing your tool's functionality (not sure you 've done it yet). About the tool, it depends on what is your application's type. If it is a GUI app then you are the best testing tool. If it is an http server or web services then the [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) (which you already added in the tags) will be quite good.